# Creating efficient join on two table with large amount of data in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with large amount of data say 1 million in one table and half a million in another now I want to extract only those values (based on single column) existing in first table but not in second one. I used following code:

```
SELECT t1.column FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column = t2.column
WHERE t2.column IS NULL;
```

Above query takes a lot of time in hours. I want to do this in efficient way.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on these tables?

Comment: No infact field to match is of varchar type

Comment: So? You can add an index on varchar too.

Answer (score 0):

DO index for all where condition fields.. then use mysql Innodb engine.. Innodb will be fast for retrieving data from database..

Comment: i did indexing as well still same problem waited for about more than an hour query was still in process and i had to quit.

Comment: use innodb for database engine.

Comment: Execute your query in cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

Myisam for reads may well be faster than innodb.

With the indexing, has it used the index for the join (do an EXPLAIN for the query). Are the columns you are joining on unique?

Failing that possibly try using EXISTS

```
SELECT t1.column
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.column = t1.column
);
```

Comment: +1 for explanation and query, -1 for claiming MyISAM is faster for reads - it really isn't, at least not any more or if you give it 20 minutes and optimize MySQL a bit.

Comment: @N.B. - My comment was it MAY well be faster for reads. Just converting a 1m record table from myisam to innodb in the hope that it will be faster is quite possibly going to result in disappointment.

Comment: Actually, it is certain it won't result in disappointment. Technically you're swapping the read from disk for reading from memory. It isn't, by definition, slower. One of the reasons for using InnoDB is this great option we have for sticking the working dataset into RAM and controlling how much RAM we allocate to it. Therefore, it's nearly always better to use InnoDB, both for writes and reads if you're able to tune your machine and allow it to shuffle and hand out data quickly.

Comment: @N.B. With a 1m record table being joined to a half million record table based on varchar fields the working data is huge. As I understand it innodb does use disk access as well for checking various things. Looking at bench marks myisam is often faster, but on others innodb is, but where one is faster than the other the difference is only maybe 1/3. Changing storage engine (with the risks and costs involved) to reduce a 1 hour query to a 40 minute query is pretty disappointing, but increasing the time would be even worse. I am not saying not to use innodb, just that it isn't a quick fix.

Comment: Well first off, let me start by saying I never trust benchmarks. They're nearly always sloppy. The other thing is that query speed depends on how fast the data gets to CPU. If it's getting there from the disk, it will be horribly slow. If it's getting there from RAM - the whole operation will be quicker. 1m joined onto 500k cannot take 40 minutes, it doesn't even take that long on my old server from 2006 that doesn't even have an SSD. I'm interested in your sources of those benchmarks, I'd be interested in re-creating them just for fun.

Comment: @N.B. The benchmarks are general ones from various places. Yes there is a performance difference, but possible to either sides benefit. The time given was based on the comments of the OP where he killed the query after it had been running for an hour once indexes had been added. Any small gain from changing storage engine (either way) is of little consequence when the query time is already so unmanageable.